# Prepare for segue Incompatible pointer

Tags: iphone, ios6, nsmutablearray, uistoryboardsegue

I'm using storyboard with TableView and plist file, using this source:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([@"detailList" isEqual:segue.identifier]) {

        NSIndexPath *index = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
        DetailViewController *detail = [_saved objectAtIndex:index.row];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setSaved:detail];
    }
}
```

And working, if I tap on a table the segue show me the correct content, but on a line:

```
[[segue destinationViewController] setSaved:detail];
```

**I have the alert says:**

> Incompatible pointer types sending
>   'DetailViewController *__strong' to parameter of type 'NSMutableArray
>   *'

What I have to do for fix and remove this alert?

Thanx

Comment: How is the `setSaved:` method declared?

Comment: Are you sure detail is actually a DetailViewController*? That would mean _saved is an array of DetailViewControllers? That doesn't seem right.

Comment: In a DetailViewController i used SAVED in mode: "@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *saved;" and in TableViewController this: "@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *saved;"

Answer (score 0):

You are sending mutable object(from `NSMutableArray`) to immutable object (`NSDictionary`)

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *saved;
```

here the `NSDictionary` is immutable and you are sending object from `NSMutableArray`(its mutable).

so just make mutable dictionary

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *saved;
```

Comment: Change it, but still continue to the same allert noe on "NSMutableDictionary" T_T

Comment: have you tried DetailViewController *detail = (DetailViewController *)[_saved objectAtIndex:index.row];